# Show User Name but hide everything else on the SharePoint Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

On SharePoint 2010 I was able to figure out how to hide the SharePoint Ribbon links (site actions -- page --browse) with the following code on the master page:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="ManageLists">

<SharePoint:SPRibbon>
...
</SharePoint:SPRibbon>

</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

But this also hides the domain\username

Where do I put the code to hide everything except the username?
I am ok with creating more than one trimmedControl.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply open your Master Page using Sharepoint Designer 2010 and add Asp.Net:LoginName control instead of SharePoint Ribbon as following

```
<asp:LoginName runat="server" id="LoginName"></asp:LoginName>
```

I hope that help

Regards.

Comment: That is really nice option to show the Username, but I am missing the functionality (sign out). How could I add the sign out functunality to the username?

Comment: Create for example ASP.Net HyperLink control and let it navigate to singout.aspx page as following example '  <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="/_layouts/signout.aspx" ID="SignOut" runat="server" Text="Sign Out"></asp:HyperLink>'

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the control in the master page that you want to not hide:

```
<wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
</wssuc:Welcome>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide your ribbon like this

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ManageLists">
    <div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">
    .
    .
    .
    </div>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Then search your code for the line Mark told you

```
<wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
</wssuc:Welcome>
```

Copy and paste the above line anywhere inside a placeholder in the master page. All I did was add a new `<td>` in the table

```
<table class="s4-titletable" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
         <td>...</td> <td>...</td> ... <td> </td>
         <td>
             <div class="s4-trc-container-menu">
                  <div>
                    <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="serve EnableViewState="false">
                    </wssuc:Welcome>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```